# Excel - generate cell value form previous cell when cells have direct relationship

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Is it possible in excel to have a cell value automatically inserted once the previous cell has been inserted, where the previous cell has a direct relationship to this one which is defined in another table.

For example:
on the first worksheet there is 2 columns: 'isbn' and 'book title', on another worksheet there is a table containing isbn values and there corresponding book titles. On the first worksheet the isbn column is a drop down that lists the isbn's from the table on worksheet2.

When the user selects a isbn from the dropdown i would like the book title column to be filled  in automatically with the corresponding title from worksheet2 table.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming sheet 1 has the dropdown for selecting input and sheet 2 has the full list of ISBNs and book titles.*

1. On sheet 1 select the cells you want the dropdown in. If you want a full column, click the column header for Sheet 1 column A.
2. Then hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> which brings up the **`Data`** tab and then the **`Data Validation`** button and to the **`Data Validation...`** option.
3. `Allow:` a `List` and select a `Source:` of `=Sheet2!A:A`. It must be a single-column source. Leave `Ignore blank` and `In-cell dropdown` checked.
4. If you want the book title to show up in column B as each dropdown is selected: Click column B header, go to **`Data Validation...`** again and `Allow:` `Custom` and select a `Source:` of `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:B, 2, FALSE),"")`.

You may want to remove duplicates on the ISBN/Title list on Sheet 2. Sorting it may also be handy.